# Using Laravel 5.5 how do I duplicate a column in a table with a migration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to duplicate a column on my existing `seasons` table using a migration in Laravel 5.5.

I can do it using SQL running these two queries:

```
ALTER TABLE seasons ADD uploader_channel_partner_id BIGINT NULL
```

then

```
UPDATE seasons set seasons.uploader_channel_partner_id = seasons.channel_partner_id
```

I am creating a system where you can transfer the ownership of videos while keeping the original uploader stored.

The up function of my migration currently just has this inside it:

```
Schema::create('seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('uploader_channel_partner_id');
    $table->foreign('uploader_channel_partner_id')->references('id')->on('channel_partners');
});
```

**EDIT:**

I've made it work with this but it's slow and ugly and I'm sure there is a better way:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('uploader_channel_partner_id')->after('channel_partner_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('uploader_channel_partner_id')->references('id')->on('channel_partners');
    });
    $seasons = Season::withTrashed()->get();
    foreach ($seasons as $key => $season) {
        $season->uploader_channel_partner_id = $season->channel_partner_id;
        $season->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DB::raw()` to force `Sql` to use another column instead of a string value.

```
Season::withTrashed()
    ->update([
        'uploader_channel_partner_id' => DB::raw('`channel_partner_id`'),
    ]);
```

Comment: This works is so much faster that what I had set up. Thanks!

Comment: perfect, if it helped please accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I would have accepted sooner but I am a new users and I thought my user perms didn't allow me to. I found the check mark upon further inspection.